# Gestionar comandos de teclas desde c# y WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola estoy intentando evitar que el usuario pueda copiar, pegar, cortar e imprimir desde mi aplicación con WPF.

Lo que he encontrado en el foro todos utilizan en el método `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` sin embargo yo tengo que utilizar `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs` porque estoy en la clase UIElement entonces el método KeyDown pide la de input entonces todo el código que he visto no me sirve ya que esta librería no tiene `e.Control`.

El problema es que creo que esta libería solo coge una tecla no las dos y esto tampoco funciona:

```
 (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.P)
```

Comment: Te refieres a que necesitas detectar combinaciones de teclas? Pq trabajas a nivel de `UIElement`en lugar de `FrameworkElement` por ejemplo? Danos un poco de contexto sobre en que tipo de control quieres detectar las combinaciones de teclas

Comment: @Pikoh la clase hereda de System.Windows.Window y los eventos me sale como UIElement, no se muy bien por qué

Comment: Vale, no te estaba entendiendo. `if (e.Key == Key.C && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)`..esto deberia capturarte CTRL+C. Si no es asi, depura e intenta darnos mas informacion, por ejemplo codigo para poder probarlo

Comment: @Pikoh e.Key es LeftCtrl no coge el valor de C

Comment: No entiendo la verdad. Exactamente que combinacion de teclas quieres detectar? Estás seguro de estar usando el evento `KeyDown`? edita la pregunta y pon el codigo del manejador del evento

Comment: @Pikoh CTRL+C CTRL+V y CTRL+P, perdona ahora veo el Edit si uso el evento KeyDown pero el de la clase UIElement hago this.KeyDown = KeyDownEventHandler; y va al método KeyDownEventHandler

Comment: El código que está en mi respuesta detecta CTRL+C. Comprobado en mi equipo. Asi que amplia y explica que evento usas, pon todo el codigo del manejador

Comment: @Pikoh          `if (e.Key == Key.C && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
                Console.WriteLine("Key: " + e.Key);    ` tu cuando haces el this.KeyDown te sale que es de UIElement.KeyDown?

Comment: Mira tu código. No ves que para que se ejecute el `Console.WriteLine` `e.Key` tiene que ser `C` por narices? Creo que el problema es que estas poniendo el `Console.WriteLine` sin comprobar primero que la tecla sea una de las buscadas (C,V,P) y claro, si pulsas `LeftControl` por supuesto que te va a marcar eso como tecla pulsada. Copia el codigo de mi respuesta y pon un `Console.WriteLine("Key: " + e.Key)` en cada `case`

Comment: @Pikoh el problema es que nunca se ejecuta el Console.WriteLine he probado con tu código del switch y nada mas de lo mismo, el e.key que llega cuando pulsas ctrl+c es LeftControl nunca llega e.key con valor c

Comment: Vale, he probado en un proyecto nuevo tu solución y funciona @Pikoh supongo que será cosa del WebControl que uso. Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Tomando de ejemplo que estás utilizando un objeto `Window`:

Declaras tus `Commands` en `Resources` de la ventana (o el objeto que uses):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="AccionAComando" Text="Se ejecuta cuando oprimes A"/>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="AccionBComando" Text="Se ejecuta cuando oprimes B"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Después les asignas las acciones (en `Executed`) y las condiciones cuando se pueden ejecutar (en `CanExecute`):

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource AccionAComando}" Executed="AccionAComando_Execucion" CanExecute="AccionAComando_Validar"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource AccionBComando}" Executed="AccionAComando_Execucion" CanExecute="AccionAComando_Validar"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Ahora solo queda asignar los comandos a los `KeyBindings`:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="A" Command="{StaticResource AccionAComando}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="B" Command="{StaticResource AccionBComando}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

P.D.: La funcion `Executed` es donde agregaras toda la logica del evento. 
Y en `CanExecuted` las condiciones para solo ejecutarlo cuando deba de hacerse. Para esto solo hay que cambiar `e.CanExecute` a `true` o `false` (segun sea el caso).

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar una combinación de teclas usando el evento `KeyDown` de una ventana WPF por ejemplo, lo unico que hay que hacer es un bitwise and de la propiedad `Keyboard.Modifiers` con la tecla de control que queremos comprobar. El siguiente ejemplo captura la combinación <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.C:
                //Ctrl+C
                break;
            case Key.V:
                //Ctrl+V
                break;
            case Key.P:
                //Ctrl+P
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

De todas maneras te recomiendo que sigas el patron de programacion introducido por WPF: [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh848246.aspx) y utilices comandos y otros métodos avanzados de enlazar eventos de teclado con funciones de tu viewmodel. Al principio es un poco duro, pero merece la pena y ese tipo de patrones de programacion parecen ser el futuro